# Scale canvas content based on the JFrame size

Tags: java, swing, canvas

So basically I'm building a mini game in Java and I would like the content of the Canvas component to scale based on the windows' size, which is a JFrame. The reason I want that is because I'm running the game in full screen, and obviously not all screens have the same dimensions.

This is the Window class, the Game argument is the main Canvas component which I want to scale based on the JFrame size:

```
public class Window{

public Window(int width, int height, String title, Game game) {

    JFrame jf = new JFrame(title);

    //Setting the window size
    jf.setSize(width, height);

    //Fullscreen window
    jf.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
    jf.setUndecorated(true);

    jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    jf.setResizable(false);
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    game.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Game.WIDTH, Game.HEIGHT));
    game.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Game.WIDTH, Game.HEIGHT));
    game.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(Game.WIDTH, Game.HEIGHT));

    jf.add(game);

    jf.setVisible(true);

    game.start();

}

}
```

This is how I get the screen dimensions and then I add those variables to the constructor of the Window class:

```
private static Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

public static final int WIDTH = (int) screenSize.getWidth(), HEIGHT = (int) screenSize.getHeight();
```

Can anyone help?

P.S. Sorry if the formating is terrible, first time posting on stackoverflow.

Comment: `This is how I get the screen dimensions` - That won't work since that size included the titlebar and the borders of the frame, so the panel added to the frame can't be the same size. In any case don't use the set???Size() methods (they don't do anything anyway). The default layout manager of a frame is a BorderLayout. When you add a component to the CENTER, then the component is automatically resized to fill all the available space in the frame. So basically you don't have to do anything. The game panel will automatically be resized.

Comment: I'm sorry I think I didn't make myself clear. I draw some objects with Graphics class and I also have some sprites which are buffered images. I can't get to resize those objects on the screen. Is there a way to do that? That's what I meant with canvas content.

Comment: There is also no need for frame.setSize(...), since the `jf.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);`  method does that automatically.

Comment: .In any case your posted code is wrong and shows you don't understand how Swing works, so you can start by fixing the simple problems.

Comment: Any recommendations on where I can learn the structure of swing and get a better understanding of it?

Comment: It's more a matter of understanding the methods that you are using. As I said above you need to think about what the setSize() and setExtendedState(..) do. Why would you think you need both methods?.   I gave you a link to the `Swing tutorial` in my answer. The tutorial examples (in most cases) use simple basic code to demonstrate basic Swing functionality. So you can check the tutorial when you do something new. For example, I'm guessing you are doing custom painting. Well there is a section on `Custom Painting` that you should look at to get you started.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Elements drawn using `Graphics2D` can be scaled using [`Graphics2D.scale(scaleX, scaleY)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#scale-double-double-) But be cautious how it is used. A circle drawn in a drawing area presumed to be square, will end up as an oval on a full-screen (land scape orientation) window.

Answer (score 0):

> I draw some objects with Graphics class and I also have some sprites which are buffered images.

You can add a `ComponentListener` to your panel. When the frame is made visible a `componentResized` event will be generated. Then you do you image scaling calculations.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a ComponentListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/componentlistener.html) for more information and working examples.